# Issues casting to custom receiver using <cast-media-player> element

Tags: jwplayer, chromecast, google-cast

I've followed [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver_basic) to create a basic custom receiver, however when I try to cast to it from Chrome, I can see the player briefly load (progress bar shows), but then it throws a `LOAD_FAILED` error and stops casting.

I then found [this sample app](https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloVideoPlayer/blob/master/receiver.html) provided by Google, which actually works, however there is no UI/progress bar while casting (which I'm interested in having). It also is using the old casting v2 library, rather than the new CAF receiver library.

After some sleuthing, it's looking like using a `<video>` element consistently works (found in their sample app), however using `<cast-media-player>` doesn't, regardless of the js used (new CAF vs old v2).

Has anyone else had issues with casting videos to a `<cast-media-player>`?

Answer (score 0):

We highly recommend that you use CAF. `<cast-media-player>` only works with CAF. If you can reproduce the issue with our samples, then please file an issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:190205%20status:open&s=modified_time:desc

The progress bar typically only displays initially when the media loads or if it is paused.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yeah, I have every intention of sticking with CAF. I'll try to reproduce the `<cast-media-player>` bug I'm seeing and file an issue. I'll post any findings here, as well. Cheers!